# Better way to create definitions

Tags: jquery, arrays, dictionary

I currently have a system where a user clicks on a word and is presented with a definition of that word. I currently have a click function with this inside:

```
                thisWord = $(this).html()

                if(thisWord == 'Every'){
                    thisDefinition = 'Each and all parts of something'
                } else if(thisWord == 'morning'){
                    thisDefinition = 'The early part of the day, beginning when the sun rises and ending about noon.'
                }  else if(thisWord == 'woke'){
                    thisDefinition = 'To come out of sleep'
                } else if(thisWord == 'up'){
                    thisDefinition = 'To come out of sleep'
                } else if(thisWord == 'feeling'){
                    thisDefinition = 'An emotion such as anger or sadness'
                } else if(thisWord == 'worried'){
                    thisDefinition = 'To feel anxious or nervous'
                } 

  $('.definition').append(thisDefinition)
```

I was just wondering, is there a better way to do this than use if statements? I was thinking about using an array of words and definitions but can't think how I could set this up and how to call it?

Comment: instead of array, use object (`{ 'woke': 'to come out of sleep', ...}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var dex={
   every:'each and all..', 
   morning:'the early part...'
}
```

Store every word in an object where `key` is the word and value is `definition` of that word.

For example, you've clicked on every:

```
function getDefinition(){
    var word= $('your selector').text().toLowerCase();
    return dex[word];
}
```

Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qxyp9r1e/) as well. I've made a `jsfiddle` for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `array` for that and applied your searching word as key parameter.

```
var defination = [];
defination['Every'] = "Each and all parts of something";
defination['morning'] = "The early part of the day, beginning when the sun rises and ending about noon.";
defination['woke'] = "To come out of sleep";
defination['up'] = "To come out of sleep";
defination['feeling'] = "Each and all parts of something";
defination['worried'] = "To feel anxious or nervous";

thisWord = $(this).html();     //thisWord = "worried"; 
alert(defination[thisWord]);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kg0pn7ez/1/)**